# Save process explorer page as a text file

Tags: batch-file

I want to check whether explorer.exe processes are running in PROCESS EXPLORER or not ? and if running, then save the full page information as a text file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch script to get information from Sysinternals PROCESS EXPLORER for any process running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357715/batch-script-to-get-information-from-sysinternals-process-explorer-for-any-proce).  Are you asking 2 separate questions or are these the same?

Comment: Hi DSway..objective of both questions are different..the only difference is: in this question i want to collect handle information also, which i have done using utility sysinternals Handle.exe..many thanks for you response..! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be two (maybe three) approaches you can take.

Use Tasklist and either Findstr or the for command to parse out the PID of the processes you are interested in. Start Process Explorer with the /s: switch. Then use a three line vbscript to send Alt + F, S, Enter, Alt + F, X. Then do the next file.

Or you can try this which will give you most of what you want

```
wmic /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\HsvDataSource.html" process where (Caption="HsvDataSource.exe") get /format:hform
```

Comment: Thanks David..!! it works..but i want to collect handle information running under any particular process also for which Handle.exe utility is quite useful..thanks for your reply..! :)